# Start long running process on webserver startup?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-applications, web

I've been away from web development for 6/7 years now and I'm completely lost in regards to how to do things.  I'm going through some tutorials on HTML5 and whatnot, but I was hoping to get a helping hand here.

I'm trying to build a (POC) website which would have the "server" monitor it's running applications and when a certain application is running change the content of a hosted page.  I don't want the model to be PageLoad->Application Check, I'd rather have something like ServerStart->ApplicationHook->Callback->Model->PageLoad->CheckModel, so a hook is put in place when the server starts and the callback of the hook updates a model which the page uses to update.  Although this architecture may not be the best way, in general I'm just looking for a way to have a long running process which starts when the server starts up.  Eventually I'l move this to a Windows service which calls a webservice when changes are made, but for a POC I'd rather keep away from multiple applications interacting, as the Windows Service would need to be "called" by the server too and I can't think of an easy implementation of that at the moment.

So, if you were building a page which relied on events on the server and needed to be able to interact with an application on the server separately to an individual page, but the page needs to be able to "post" information back to that application what would you do?

My explanation has been a bit all over the place, so I hope at some point my question has come across clearly! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there're alternatives but I think your only option for this kind of setup is a Windows service. If you need to talk to it from other components, have it use sockets or listen for HTTP requests on a known port. Doing what you described from a web application is not impossible but it'd be certainly very hard since it's the web server (app pool executable) that controls what happens in the process, not your code. In a Windows service, you're in control.

**Edit:** here's an [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx) about the different options for hosting a web service - it seems to me that using a Windows service is, indeed, your best choice. You may be able to use a WCF service but you'll have to talk to a local application on the server and that part may be easier to do just using a Windows service.

Comment: How could I make the WCF service hosted in my Windows service watch my applications?  I can't find an onstart for WCF... Or should I make the Windows service do that work?  If so, how do I make the WCF service and Windows service communicate with each other?

Comment: @Vijay I'm not very familiar with WCF so I can't answer that part of your question. I'd just create a standalone Windows service and then have it listen to a port. When necessary the WCF service can open that port and send a message to the Windows service. The point of it is that a web application runs inside an app pool and if the app pool is recycled, the web application is recycled, too. Plus the app pool may not start until the first request. If you need a service that runs at startup, a Windows service is your best option.

Comment: @Vijay I edited the answer with a link to an article, see if that helps.